# Push object to array in mongodb nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

[This is my mongodb collection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHod5.png)

I want to push object to array with findOneAndUpdate().

This is my nodejs code.

```
url = req.params.posturl
         filter = { url: url }
         update = { comments: (result.like + 1) }
         // maybe you can try save/get this to/in .json
         Blog.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update)
            .then((result) => {
               res.json({ status: 1 })
            })
            .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
            })
```

How can i do this?

Comment: how you comments array looks? and what is your input `result` variable contains? please try to post document instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$push`  operator for updating an array. Actually you have a few ways too for updating a document like `$set` operator or find one and change the document then save new document this will be update your document.
TLDR code here;

```
const url = req.params.posturl
const newComment = req.body.comment
const filter = { url }
const willBePush = { comments: newComment }
Blog.findOneAndUpdate(filter, { $push: willBePush })
  .then((result) => {
    /** Do whatever with response if you want to see new document you can pass { new: true } as option for findOneAndUpdate method*/
    console.log(result)    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

References:

[$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

[$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)

[mongoose documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html)

Comment: Your welcome @AbdiKaan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
         url = req.params.posturl
         filter = { url: url }
         Blog.findOne(filter)
            .then((result) => {
               result.like ++;
               return result.save();
            })
            .then(result => {
               res.json({status: 1});
             })
            .catch((error) => {
               console.log(error);
            })
```

I think you got the idea. I didn't get what comments is, but this is the way you should try

Comment: I mean like youtube comments. User signs in and comments to blog post.

Comment: So, comment is a nested object inside blog post, and inside comment you have like?

Answer (score 0):

Use Node.js driver's `returnOriginal:false` as a third argument to your DB call. Change the line to:

```
filter = { url: url }
update = { comments: (result.like + 1) }
return = { returnOriginal: false }
Blog.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, return)
```

Some people are using Mongoose to avoid such complexities. Node.js documentation is great but not so readable.